# C# Image comparison. Search one in the other

Tags: c#, image, comparison

I have two images.

One is big and the other is small.  I need an image comparison code/library which will search for the small one in the big one and give me the location and the percentage of the compared.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to make a comparing method yourself or use a library? Have you tried to [Google](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=C%23+find+image+in+image) it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emgu is opencv (open computer vision) in .Net.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

This will have more than enough functionality to do what you are asking for.

EDIT: I am assuming that C# is a key requirement.